# Me da un error al querer cambiar un carácter dentro de una frase

Tags: c++, string, funciones

Buen día, anduve haciendo un programa en C++ para que me devuelva el texto que le puse con las a en mayúsculas, ejemplo; entrada: palabra. salida: pAlAbrA.
El problema es que a la hora de compilar me tira un error en la línea 19 en medio de la 'a' y el ).
Muy probablemente sea por la variable char, el problema es que no lo se usar y se que tengo errores que todavía no se corregir, y por encima soy nuevo en C++, sepan entender, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string CambiarPalabra(string palabra);

int main () {
    char * p = new char[30];
    string aCambiada;
    cout << "Ingrese palabra(s): " << endl;
    cin.getline(p,30,'\n');
    cout <<CambiarPalabra(p)<< endl;
    
    return 0;
}

string CambiarPalabra(string palabra) {
    if (palabra = 'a') {
        palabra = 'A';
    }
    return palabra;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu variable `*p` es un  `arreglo de char`, la función `CambiarPalabra` recibe como parametro un dato de tipo `string`.
En la función `CambiarPalabra` tienes que recorrer cada posición de la palabra ingresada y comparar `a`  para realizar el cambio.
No es necesario que declares tantas varibles, te dejo tu código corregido

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string CambiarPalabra(string palabra);

int main () {    
    string palabra;
    cout << "Ingrese palabra(s): " << endl;
    cin>>palabra;    
    cout <<CambiarPalabra(palabra)<< endl;
    
    return 0;
}

string CambiarPalabra(string cadena) {
  for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    if (cadena[i] == 'a') 
      cadena[i]='A';          
  }     
  return cadena;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realice algunos cambios a tu código

```
string CambiarPalabra(string & palabra);
```

Aca estamos referenciando a la funcion de tipo string y tambien lo paso por parametro de direccion de memoria a la palabra digitada para modificarla.

```
string palabra;
cout << "Ingrese palabra: ";
cin>>palabra;    
cout <<"La nueva palabra es: "<<CambiarPalabra(palabra);
```

En el código anterior le di una variable de tipo string a la palabra que vamos a digitar y después llamamos a la función CambiarPalabra(palabra) para su respectivo análisis.

```
  string CambiarPalabra(string & cadena) {
  for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    if (cadena[i] == 'a'){ 
      cadena[i]='A'; 
    }else{
        continue;
    }
  }     
  return cadena;
}
```

En el código anterior estamos pasando por parámetro la dirección de memoria de mi palabra digitada.
Después recorremos cada digito de la palabra ingresada y verificamos si es igual a 'a' para modificarla a 'A'. en caso contrario un continue para que no haga ningún cambio.